# Two aeroplanes $1$ and $2$ bomb a target in succession. Probability of $1$ and $2$ hitting correctly are $0.3$ and $0.2$.

Tags: probability

> Two aeroplanes $1$ and $2$ bomb a target in succession. Probability of $1$ and $2$ hitting correctly are $0.3$ and $0.2$. The second plane will bomb only if first misses the target. Find the probability that target is bombed by the second plane

I want to know why the complementary method cannot be used here i.e. $$P(B) = 1-0.3=0.7$$

Which gives the probability that the target is never hit by the first plane.

Answer is 0.318

**Note: I know the correct way to do this, I just want to know why this is wrong.**

Comment: Is the question asking whether plane 2 drops a bomb at all or whether it actually hits the target?

Comment: @QC_QAOA plane 2 hits the target

Comment: do you know conditional probability?

Comment: Then all you have calculated so far is the probability plane 2 drops a bomb at all. Not that it actually hits

Comment: Does https://www.toppr.com/ask/en-in/question/two-aeroplanes-i-and-ii-bomb-a-target-in-succession-the-probabilities-of-i-and/ helps?

Comment: After the target is never hit by the first plane we arrive at two cases it is hit by second plane and it is missed by the second plane. So we need to multiply it by 0.2 to get the probability that it is missed by the first and hit by the second plane.

Comment: Yes $0.7$ is the probability that the second plane will drop a bomb but there is only $0.2$ chance that it would hit the target.

Comment: @alimansoor yes

Comment: @ArchisWelankar the answer is 0.318

Comment: Either the answer is wrong or you cite the question incorrectly.

Comment: @user : the question is incorrect: the two planes bomb the target in succession until the target is hit...

Comment: @tommik I have expected this.

Comment: @tommik I did write the question exactly as it was. I don’t understand how the question is incomplete. Doesn’t it already imply that planes bomb the target until it is already hit?

Comment: @Aditya : reading the text I understood they shot not more than once. Given that they shot until the target is hit the solution is simply the result of a geometric series. See my edited answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probability that target is hit by plane #2  is  the probability of a composite event: plane #1 fails AND plane #2 hits, thus

$$(1-0.3)\times 0.2 = 0.14$$

---

EDIT : understood that the request is " they bomb the target in succession until they hit" the solution is simply the series

$$\mathbb{P}[\text{#2}]=0.7\cdot 0.2 \sum_{i=0}^{\infty}(0.8\cdot 0.7)^i=0.7\cdot 0.2\cdot\frac{1}{1-0,56}=0.3181818...$$

Your solution is wrong because the probability that #1 never hits is not simply 0,7 but it is a result of a series too and goes to 0

In fact

$$\mathbb{P}[\text{#1}]=0.3 \sum_{i=0}^{\infty}(0.8\cdot 0.7)^i=0.3\cdot\frac{1}{1-0,56}=0.6818181...$$

Thus

$$\mathbb{P}[\text{#1}]+\mathbb{P}[\text{#2}]=1$$

Comment: The answer is 0.318

Comment: @Aditya : the probability of #2 to hit is 0 2, but it is not sure that he shots. Considering this the probability that the target is hit by #2 cannot be higher than 0.2 unless there is a different conditional probability $P(#2|#1)$ that you didn't tell. IMHO

Comment: I typed the question as it is.

Comment: Also there is a conditional probability; #1 has to always miss

Comment: I think you've matched up the given answer with the intended interpretation, given a terribly worded question. I'd never interpret as the planes keep bombing until the target is hit, particularly because they specify the conditions under which the second plane releases bombs, but specify no such condition for the first plane. Furthermore, they overload the term "bomb" to mean both "releases bombs" (the second plane will bomb if the first misses) and "hits the target with bombs" (what is the probability that the target is bombed by plane 2), which are very different. Good answer, bad question.

Answer (score 0):

There's a second way to reach the correct answer that avoids needing to sum a series.  The key insight is to note that if both planes miss on their first pass (which happens with probability $0.56$), you're right back where you started.  Thus, $P(A)=0.3+0.56 P(A)$, so $P(A)=\frac{0.3}{0.44}$ and $P(B)=1-P(A)=\frac{0.14}{0.44}=\frac{7}{22}$.

Comment: How did you find $0.56$?

Comment: @Aditya The probability that we reach a second round because both planes miss their first shots is $(1-0.3)(1-0.2)=0.56$.

Comment: So what are $P(A)$ and $P(B)$ supposed to be here?

Comment: @Aditya The probability that the target is hit by plane $1$ or plane $2$, respectively.